# Export Qlikview report to Excel

Tags: vbscript, macros, qlikview

I have created a `Qlikview` report that I would like to export to a `Excel` spreadsheet. The report has 8 sheets/tabs and navigation functionality on all. After some research I found that I need to create a `button` on the report that executes a `macro`.

Having the limited experience in `Qlikview` as I do, I was only able to go as far as to create the `button`.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction or better yet, provide me with a `macro`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an action on the button and select external - run macro.
In the macro name field you type the name of your macro function/subroutine (in this case "MacroTest").

By pressing "Edit module..." you can access the macro edit mode (or by pressing Ctrl + M)

```
sub MacroTest
  msgbox("macro")
end sub
```

Press the button and a message box will appear.

Regarding excel exports there are a lot of working examples you can find by google.

Good luck
//Micke

Comment: Thanks, I have spoken to Qlikview about my requirements and they have informed me that I can only extract underlying data and would thus lose all functionality. However, your answer about exporting the data is correct.